# how to pass arguments dynamically?

Tags: dynamic, flutter, dart, widget

I'm trying to create a button next to a title but instead of passing the content in the beginning I'm trying to do it it dynamically so I used constructors but instead of getting the values I pass when I call the constructor I keep getting null. So how can i pass arguments dynamically using constructors or any other mean? Here are the classes I'm using

```
class Header extends StatefulWidget {

String buttonTitle;
String title;

Header(String buttonTitle , String title) //the constructor I'm gonna 
call
{
this.buttonTitle = buttonTitle;
this.title = title;
}

@override
HeaderState createState() => HeaderState(buttonTitle , title);
}


class HeaderState extends State<Header> {
String buttonTitle;
String title;

HeaderState(String buttonTitle , String title)
{
this.buttonTitle = buttonTitle;
this.title = title;
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//some code
Text("$title", //the first parameter passed dynamically),

RaisedButton(
child: Text(
"$buttonTitle", //the second parameter
),
}


class FirstScreen extends StatefulWidget {
@override
FirstScreenState createState() => FirstScreenState();
}  


class FirstScreenState extends State<FirstScreen> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
Header("OK", "Page1"),//constructor is called here 
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to make reusable widget, you made several mistakes so you can compare that with below code. below is fully working code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(FirstScreen());

class Header extends StatefulWidget {
  final String buttonTitle;
  final String title;

  Header({this.buttonTitle, this.title});

  @override
  HeaderState createState() => HeaderState();
}

class HeaderState extends State<Header> {
  String buttonTitle;
  String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(children: [
      Text("${widget.title}"),
      RaisedButton(
        child: Text("${widget.buttonTitle}"),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    ]);
  }
}

class FirstScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  FirstScreenState createState() => FirstScreenState();
}

class FirstScreenState extends State<FirstScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Header(buttonTitle: "OK", title: "Page1"),
        ),
        body: Header(buttonTitle: "Reuse", title: "Reuse in body"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just call your *Header* class in Scaffold directly. You must assign it to some property of Scaffold such as

```
Scaffold(
body: Header("OK", "Page1"),
);
```

and you can also try using *widget.variable_name* instead of using dollar symbol to call variable value.

```
Text(widget.title,),

RaisedButton(
child: Text(
widget.buttonTitle,
),
```